# Validation For Picklist

Tags: picklist, validation, validation-rule

I have picklist Name Status__c and values are Active, Canceled, Closed And other filed is Amount__c.
My requirement is when I choose Canceled or Closed values from Picklist the Amount filed should not update and Amount__c filed already has values stored I cannot change stored values when I choose canceled or close. which means I cannot save it. only when I choose Active value I can update the Amount__c   filed.

AND(
OR(
ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Closed"),
ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Cancelled")
),
ISBLANK(Text(Amount__c)
)
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation rule wants to be something like:

```
ISCHANGED(Amount__c) && (ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Closed') || ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Cancelled'))
```

In essence, fail validation when a change is made to Amount in status Closed or Cancelled.